# Laptop battery discharge jump/non-linear - replace?

Tags: laptop, battery-life

I have a 3yr old laptop, Acer 1810T olympic edition. Battery parameters, as written on the battery itself: 11.1V, 5.27Ah, 5600mAh, 63Wh. What's been happening lately is that it goes normally down to approximately 50% of the charge and then instantly down to 5%, and hibernates (Windows setting). If I bring it up, it shows 5%, which will last ~5-10 minutes and then die completely, until recharged.

I tried to burn-in using Aida64 (100% CPU usage) down to those 5% and then recharge to 100% several times - seems to have no impact on battery scale (same 50% -> 5% jump).

My BIOS does not support any sort of battery calibration.

Can I do something else about it? Is it enough evidence that I need to replace the battery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  This is enough evidence to replace the battery.  I am almost certain that the issue is with one or more of the cells in the battery is in worse condition than the rest.  Remember, your battery is made up of rechargeable cells.  If it helps to visualize it, your battery is made up of the equivalent of nine AA rechargeable batteries (although if you want to be technical, there are actually three 3.7v rechargeable cells within your battery).

If one of those cells is bad, as in it discharges faster than the others, when fully charged it will report that the entire battery is at 100%.  However, as the whole charge drops, the cells will not discharge evenly, and when that one cell is depleted, it will affect the total reported charge.

It's an Acer, and you got 3 years out of the battery.  That's a good run.  Pick up another battey, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. +1, accept and off looking for a decent battery replacement. :)